# Uploading Font as JSON on Server to call for WebApp: Specific Example for Dissolving font

Tags: javascript, json, responsive-design, google-webfonts, webfont-loader

How can I change the font of "FUTURE IS NOW" to Helvetica on this link:
https://codepen.io/sanprieto/pen/XWNjBdb

For reference, the current lines of code are in the js window in line 8-10:
`const loader = new THREE.FontLoader( manager ); const font = loader.load('https://res.cloudinary.com/dydre7amr/raw/upload/v1612950355/font_zsd4dr.json', function ( font ) { typo = font; });`

Ideally, I'd like to center the text since it is a little bit off. I can't find a way to upload e. g. Helvetica with an url that goes like https://example.com/fonts/helvetica.json

I tried to search for some way on google fonts, but couldnt really figure it out.
I'm not even sure that if I found another link, it woul work nicely with the particle part and the .png file right beneath it...